# LLVM, how to get variable name?

Tags: llvm

I've read many posts here and on other sites, but still didn't get clear answer.
Let's say I have instruction and I can print it out by

```
errs() << inst << "\n";
```

and I got:
%9 = add nsw i32 %7, %8
I want to get variables names behind %9, %7, %8.
Is it possible? and if it is, how?
Thank you :)

Comment: On the IR level, these **are** instruction names. If you produced your IR from C or some other language, look into DebugInfo stuff.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In LLVM IR, how can I print the name of a unnamed value which is represented as an unsigned numeric value with their prefix such as %2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732839/in-llvm-ir-how-can-i-print-the-name-of-a-unnamed-value-which-is-represented-as)

Answer (score 0):

From here [How to save the variable name when use clang to generate llvm ir？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432967/how-to-save-the-variable-name-when-use-clang-to-generate-llvm-ir)

```
clang -fno-discard-value-names <your-command-line>
```

does the job :)